# How can we redirect facebook login page to another page of same website in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

Controller file.

```
public function login()
{
    $userData = array();
    if($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
    {
        $userProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email');
        $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
        $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
        $userData['firstname'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
        $userData['lastname'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
        $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
        $userData['password'] = rand();
        $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
        if(!empty($userID))
        {
            $data['userData'] = $userData;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['userData'] = array();
        }
        $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
    }
    else
    {
        $fbuser = '';
        $data['authUrl'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
    }
    $data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
    $this->load->view('header-inside',$data);
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
}
```

In my code I have created `facebook` login page in CodeIgniter which is working perfectly. When I have login with `facebook` in my website it have redirect me on the same page but I want to redirect to another page. So how can I do this?

Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put redirect('route name') or window.location = "route name"

Assumed that you have route name "home". in routes.php file such as

**routes.php**

```
$route['home']      = 'cHome/index';
```

---

put redirect in your log in success condition after you get userData in session then redirect to home controller and load view inside home controller.

**Controller file**

```
        if(!empty($userID))
        {
            $data['userData'] = $userData;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            redirect('home');
        }
```